# Dropout and LSTM layers

Tags: lstm, dropout

Consider the following code:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 20, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.4))
```

An LSTM layer consists of LSTM cells ( 20 cells in the above code ) and one cell consists of traditional NN operations ( for example point-wise multiplication and tanh activation function) and gates. One way to view the gates is to see them as neurons. I am aware that there are  dropouts within the LSTM layer through the arguments `dropout` and `recurrent_dropout`. So I am confused,  what is the difference between dropout done by the arguments `dropout` and `recurrent_dropout` of LSTM layer and the dropout done by the dropout layer, as above `Dropout(0.4)` ?